# Changing date format (NA error)

Tags: r, date

So I have this data file which includes dates and other values. I've imported my data using the following code:

```
df <- read.csv(file.choose(), header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

This is so that all the values in the data frame are in character. This makes the next step easier for me.

The data.frame (df) includes:

```
date        x
20020102    1
20020102    2
```

The date changes every few thousand rows.

I want to change the date format so that it would be yyyy-mm-dd.

I've tried using the code:

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

and have also used

```
df$date <- strptime(df$date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

but have always gotten NA values in the date column.

I'm a beginner at R so it would be very helpful if the solution could be simple or can be explained clearly.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the correct `format`

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format='%Y%m%d')
```

It is not clear whether you have numeric or non-numeric 'date' column.  If it is 'numeric', convert to 'character' first

```
df$date <- as.Date(as.character(df$date), format='%Y%m%d')
```

But, `strptime` would work even if the column is `numeric`.

Or using `library(lubridate)`

```
library(lubridate)
ymd(df$date)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your colunm "date" is not of class 'Date', it is a 'numeric' vector, thus the command `as.Date` returns NA`s.

You can check if the class of the colunm date is correct with this command:

```
class(df$date)
```

Following the advise from @akrun you should transform the date colunm into a 'character' vector, then you can format the style the way you want:

```
### your data example:
df <- data.frame(date = c(20020102, 20020102),
             x = c(1,2))
class(df$date)
#> [1] "numeric"

#convert the colunm date to character
df$date <- as.character(df$date)

# Then, convert to the desired date format:
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format='%Y%m%d')

# check the results:
df
#>         date x
#> 1 2002-01-02 1
#> 2 2002-01-02 2

class(df$date)
#> [1] "Date"
```